# Hiding a Button until last filled image view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, button, hide

Hello I want a button to hide until my last image view has been filled.

this is my code but it doesn't work can someone tell me why

```
if (imageview6.image == nil)

{
play.hidden=TRUE;
}
```

If I do

```
if (imageview6.image == nil)

{
[play.hidden=TRUE];
}
```

it gives me 'expected identifier'

hope someone knows bye

**EDIT WHAT DID I DO**:

I set play.enabled=YES; in this code:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
if (imageview1.image == nil) {
    [imageview1 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview2.image == nil){
    [imageview2 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview3.image == nil){
    [imageview3 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview4.image == nil){
    [imageview4 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview5.image == nil){
    [imageview5 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview6.image == nil){
    play.enabled=YES;
    [imageview6 setImage:image];
} 
}
```

and in ViewDidLoad section:

```
play.enabled=NO;
```

Hope I helped someone else with this too :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
play.hidden= YES; //to hide 
play.enabled= YES; // to prevent the action
```

you need to set hidden is yes / no

Comment: O thanks I already tried it but It was not hidden stupid mistake I have to press it of course -.- I want it to hide automatically and show only when imageview6 is filled. you know how to do this?

Comment: play.hidden= YES; //to hide
play.enabled= YES; // to prevent the action

Try these in -(void)viewDidAppear as well

Comment: what should I put in at the questions mark?- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    play.hidden=YES;
    if (imageview6.image == ???)
        
    {
        play.enabled=YES;
    }

Comment: No didn't get it work but now it works for me let me edit the post so if everybody can see what I did

Answer (score 2):

```
[Play setHidden:YES];

//or

 Play.hidden=YES;
```

Hope, this will Help you..

Comment: O thanks I already tried it but It was not hidden stupid mistake I have to press it of course -.- I want it to hide automatically and show only when imageview6 is filled. you know how to do this?

Comment: Owh TRUE works aswel I just forgot to hide button maybe hide it from viewdidload and then set if (imageview6.image == nil)

{
play.hidden=NO;
}

Comment: Ok..good..it may happen..But when you use [play.hidden=TRUE] "[]" at that time user setHidden method and don't use play.hidden with bracket....So,that was your mistake...

Answer (score 0):

use either:
[Play setHidden:YES];
   //or
   Play.hidden=YES;

**Rule of thumb:**: BOOL - YES/NO. bool - true/false.
hope it help you.
:)